# File upload in Android WebView for SDK 33-34

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I have an Android Studio project with a simple WebView. Whenever I try to use the file uploader (standard HTML input for files) in my WebApp nothing happens. However, when I use the same file uploader via Google Chrome on my phone it works just fine.

I found lots of posts about this subject on Stack Overflow and other websites, but all are out-dated and do not work for SDK 33-34.

Does anyone know how to build a webview app that can work with a file uploader? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same issue and I still didnt find a solution.